# Is this small BackBone app correct? Am I using the conventions properly?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

This is my simple Backbone app, I'm learning as I go. (It's written in coffeescript)

The idea is, I have a x-y grid of pages (1-1, 2-1, 1-2, 2-2 etc.). The page loads, and instantiates a collection with these IDs. As the user navigates around (only left and right at the moment), the model loads from the server in it's entirety, including some HTML to display.

It contains a model, and collection and a view, but I'm willing to bet I'm doing things in the wrong places! Please let me know what's wrong.

```
Page = Backbone.Model.extend 

  displayHTML: (model, response) -> 
    $("#content").html(model.get('html'))


Pages = Backbone.Collection.extend
  model: Page
  url: "/pages"
  current_page: '1-1'

  initialize: (models, options) -> 
    this.fetch(success: this.displayFirst)

  displayFirst: (collection, response) ->
    model = collection.get(collection.current_page)
    model.fetch(success: model.displayHTML)

  nextPage: ->
    id = "#{new Number(this.current_page[2]) + 1}-1" #todo - this will break with 9+
    this.gotoPage(id)

  previousPage: ->
    id = "#{new Number(this.current_page[2]) - 1}-1" #todo - this will break with 9+
    this.gotoPage(id)

  gotoPage: (id) ->
    this.current_page = id
    if model = this.get(id)
      model.fetch(success: model.displayHTML)
    else
      alert("Eh nooo")

AppView = Backbone.View.extend
  el: $('body')

  events: 
    "click #next-page": "nextPage"
    "click #previous-page": "previousPage"

  initialize: -> 
    this.pages = new Pages(null, {view:this})

  nextPage: -> this.pages.nextPage()
  previousPage: -> this.pages.previousPage()


appView = new AppView
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's working like you want it to then it's correct :) but there are some changes you can make to take advantage of certain features CoffeeScript+Backbone together give you.

The first is declaring a class, you could write it this way to be more concise.

```
class Pages extends Backbone.Collection
```

The correct JavaScript will be generated.

Another change you could make is to replace all the instances of `this.` with `@`. You'd go from typing 5 characters to only 1.

Here's a rewrite of what you posted with these changes. Hopefully I didn't miss anything.

```
class Page extends Backbone.Model
  displayHTML: (model, response) -> 
    $("#content").html(model.get('html'))


class Pages extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Page
  url: "/pages"
  current_page: '1-1'

  initialize: (models, options) -> 
    @fetch(success: @displayFirst)

  displayFirst: (collection, response) ->
    model = collection.get(collection.current_page)
    model.fetch(success: model.displayHTML)

  nextPage: ->
    id = "#{new Number(@current_page[2]) + 1}-1" #todo - this will break with 9+
    @gotoPage(id)

  previousPage: ->
    id = "#{new Number(@current_page[2]) - 1}-1" #todo - this will break with 9+
    @gotoPage(id)

  gotoPage: (id) ->
    @current_page = id
    if model = @get(id)
      model.fetch(success: model.displayHTML)
    else
      alert("Eh nooo")

class AppView extends Backbone.View
  el: $('body')

  events: 
    "click #next-page": "nextPage"
    "click #previous-page": "previousPage"

  initialize: -> 
    @pages = new Pages(null, {view:@})

  nextPage: -> @pages.nextPage()
  previousPage: -> @pages.previousPage()


appView = new AppView
```

Comment: Curiosity about appview: why not use `tagName: 'body'`?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, very useful :)

Things I'm concerned about, people have mentioned that view-rendering isn't a Model's concern, so I'll try to change that.

Any other ideas for how my structure is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you could use a view to change the html.

And the `new Pages()` shouldn't be called in the initialize method.
I prefer this way:
    class AppView extends Backbone.View
        render: () ->
            @collection # @collection refers to your Pages collection

```
pagesCollection = new Pages()

appView = new AppView(
    collection: pagesCollection
)
```

Because I think models, collections shouldn't know about the views.

Comment: Not entirely sure how to hook up render in this scenario. Could you please explain, or link to an example?

Comment: Here's an application (it's written in JavaScript and not by me):
http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/dHrXv/9/embedded/result,js,html,css/

I hope it helps you.